# ContinueWith task unexpectedly executed

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am writing sequences of task that should execute based on the success or failure of antecedent tasks. However, one of the tasks executes unexpectedly, even though its antecedent task does not execute.

The steps are, I import some data. If that succeeds, I initiate a save, then a calculate. If the import fails, I want to handle the exception.

Here's the simplest code I could reproduce it with:

```
var importTask = new Task(() => {
   Console.WriteLine("import");
   // Force an exception
   throw new Exception("FAIL");
});

var saveTask = importTask.ContinueWith(task => {
   Console.WriteLine("save");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

var calcTask = saveTask.ContinueWith(task => {
   Console.WriteLine("calc");
});

var errorTask = importTask.ContinueWith(task => {
   Console.WriteLine("error");
   Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

importTask.Start();
```

The output from this is:

import

calc

error

FAIL

I thought that calcTask should execute after saveTask. However it executes even if saveTask doesn't. Interestingly, within the calcTask, task.IsCanceled == true.

Why is the calc task executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to add

```
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
```

to each of the subsequent items to make sure they are not run except when the antecedents were run to completion, otherwise it is fair game and it will simply run sequentially weather it fails or runs.

I used this and it seemed to respond as you wanted.

```
var calcTask = saveTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
     Console.WriteLine("calc");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var importTask = new Task(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("import");
    // Force an exception
    throw new Exception("FAIL");
});

var saveTask = importTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("save");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

var calcTask = saveTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("calc");
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

var errorTask = importTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("error");
    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Using `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted` on `calcTask` won't work because `saveTask` doesn't throw any exception. You must use TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion to specify that `calcTask` should only be executed if `saveTask` was executed properly. You can find further information regarding `TaskContinuationOptions` on :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx